# Behaviour of `sudo apt upgrade` when package is installed from a different source

Tags: debian, apt

Suppose there are two package sources

```
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm main
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian unstable main
```

Then have installed a package from unstable using `sudo apt -t unstable install foo`

Now when i run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` will `foo` take update from `bookworm` or `unstable`.

Comment: `apt upgrade` will install latest version of a package available in any of the configured sources. If `unstable main` has the latest version, it will come from there; if `bookwork main` has the latest version, it will come from there instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on whether `foo` is newer in unstable than in Bookworm; since the latter was released recently, it’s possible that unstable has the same version. If that’s the case, `foo` will continue to track Bookworm rather than unstable.

However, since you’re asking the question, I’m guessing `foo` is newer in unstable. In that case, even if Bookworm is your default release (which gives a very high priority to versions in Bookworm), `apt upgrade` will upgrade `foo` to the latest version available in any configured repository.

See [`man apt_preferences`](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/apt/apt_preferences.5) for details.

(I’m assuming you’ve configured the default release to be Bookworm, or set up pinning; otherwise `apt upgrade` would update your entire installation to unstable, not just `foo`. In any case, unless you pin Bookworm to a priority greater than 1000, once you have a version of `foo` newer than the version in Bookworm, `apt upgrade` won’t ever downgrade it.)

Comment: All your assumptions are correct. What I want is only few packages (ex. `foo`) will be install from and take update from `unstable`. Rest of them will take update from `bookworm` when using `apt update && apt upgrade`. How can I do that?