# Selected packages should use `unstable` repository, Rest of them should use `stable` repository

Tags: debian, apt

I have added two package sources

```
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm main
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian unstable main
```

I want to install `fzf` and `rofi` from `unstable`. I also want them take update from `unstable` when i run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade.`

I want all other packages to use `bookworm` for both install and update.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that [you’ve set the default release to Bookworm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/749755/86440), you can specifically track packages in unstable by pinning them. Add a file in `/etc/apt/preferences.d` with the following content:

```
Package: fzf rofi
Pin: release a=unstable
Pin-Priority: 990
```

This will make unstable the default release for those two packages.